Can I make a roux with matzoh meal?
Passover question!
Is is possible to make a passable and useful roux using matzoh meal instead of flour?  Or does the fact that the meal is precooked cause it to just burn?
Is there passover gumbo in my future, or no?

The point of a roux is to turn uncooked flour into cooked flour to thicken. considering matzo is cooked... wouldn't a sufficiently fine matzo work directly as a thickener?

Well, yes and no, @JourneymanGeek. The lighter roux are mostly thickeners, but for dishes like gumbo, you make a quite dark roux, which is more for flavor and not so much for thickening. There’s an inverse correlation between thickening and browning. (We do have a post on that somewhere on the site…)

Also, the idea of roux is that you're combining fat and starch, which works far better as a thickener than either one does by itself.

I'd suggest using potato starch or similar to make a roux, rather than matzoh meal. That definitely works as a thickener for sauces and such, but I've never cooked it darker so I don't know if that would work.

I thought that it was the leaveners that were not allowed during Passover, not the flour.  If that’s the case, roux should still be allowed.

@Joe leaveners are not the problem, leavened foods made with certain grains (wheat included) are the problem. Those grains are assumed to start leavening on their own (a la sourdough) after a fairly short time, so practically speaking flour is generally not used except under very controlled circumstances when baking matzah. It's just too easy to make a mistake, especially if the baker/chef doesn't know all the associated laws.

Yes, certainly. Matzo meal has roughly the same carbohydrates as raw flour, but hydrated. It's actually similar to Wondra flour, which likewise is precooked and which is specifically intended for thickening.
You won't be able to make a light/blond roux; the mild toast aroma of matzo will come through too strongly. For a dark roux that won't matter, of course.

You can give it a try,  It won't work the same as other thickener's but if used in sufficient quantity it will thicken the mixture.  But why is a good question?     The flour is a roux thickens as well as flavors.  White thickens the best.  dark flavors the best but does not thicken much  What are you trying to achieve?  Shrimp at passover?

Yes, you can make a roux with matzoh meal! Matzoh meal works as a substitute for flour in a roux, which is used to thicken sauces or soups. To make it, simply combine equal parts of matzoh meal and fat (like butter or oil) in a pan over medium heat. Stir constantly until the mixture is smooth and slightly browned, then gradually add your liquid to create a rich, thickened sauce.

Please don’t post AI-generated content.
